# Capture UDP multicast stream with Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

I am working on a small project in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I want to capture an UDP multicast stream and get a frame from the stream to do image processing. I use opencv3.3.1 and python3.4 My codes :

```
   import numpy,cv2
   cap = cv2.VideoCapture('udp://@239.0.0.1:1234')
   print (cap.isOpened())
```

Right i want to check if  the stream is captured first. However, the program freeze at the VideoCapture line. In my opencv build, i have ffmpeg and gstreamer installed. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try this url: `'udp://239.0.0.1:1234'` without `'@'`

Comment: It still froze for me. Is it possible to capture a frame using import socket method in python?